# Distance metrics in Java

Tags: java, machine-learning, nearest-neighbor

I am working on nearest neighbor search project and I need distance metrics
such as Euclidian, Manhatan, etc. I can either implement them myself or, I
was wondering if there is standard java code I could use?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at Apaches ArrayRealVector which implements the RealVector-Interfaces.

There you have implementations for L-1, L-inf and euklidian norm and metrik for an n-dimensional vector.

https://code.google.com/p/symja/source/browse/trunk/commons-math/src/main/java/org/apache/commons/math3/linear/ArrayRealVector.java?r=883

Comment: That pulls in a lot of code for just the two 1 liners OP needs...

Comment: You do not have to import the whole class if you do not want to. But it contains a lot of useful method if you have to handle n-dimensional vectors. You can just take the methods to calculate the norms and/or distances, thats why i postet the link to the source-code

Answer (score 3):

The Manhattan distance is easy to implement with [`Math.abs(x1-x2)+Math.abs(y1-y2)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html).

Although you can use [`Point2D.distance(x1,y1,x2,y2)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Point2D.html#distance%28double,%20double,%20double,%20double%29) method for the Euclidean distance, calculating it is not hard at all:

```
double dx = x1-x2, dy = y1-y2;
Math.sqrt(dx*dx+dy*dy);
```

If you must expand this to higher dimensions, pass coordinates as arrays, and use a loop to compute the sum of squares.

Comment: I feel like a 2 argument version of that function would be more concise.  I wonder why it's designed that way.

Comment: I guess I can't use Point2D since the dimensionality of the date is undefined, it can be anything. Thanks for the Manhattan distance ;)

Comment: @user1796942: Of the ... uh... date?  perhaps you meant data?  Also, you can just use zero for the other arguments.

Comment: @user1796942 Euclidean distance is not too hard to do manually - after all, that Euclid dude has figured it out more than 2300 years ago ;-) Take a look at the edit.

Comment: @Wug `Point2D` has overloads with one, two, and four arguments, taking `Point2D`, `x` and `y`, and `x1,y1,x2,y2`.

Comment: This is how I did Euclid for start: http://pastebin.com/EJ8gE9kd Oops forgot to remove the size parameter, dont need it.

Comment: @user1796942 I would probably stay with `double[]` arrays to avoid boxing/unboxing; this would speed things up a little.

Comment: Yeah I am doing that now. I tried to copy these metrics here from c++: https://github.com/mariusmuja/flann/blob/master/src/cpp/flann/algorithms/dist.h#L90 For some reason he complicates things a lot

Answer (score 2):

Some wheels are too small to bother trying not to reinvent.

```
public class Distances
{
    private Distances() {}

    public static euclidean(double a, double b)
    {
        return Math.sqrt(a * a + b * b);
    }

    public static manhatten(double a, double b)
    {
        return Math.abs(a) + Math.abs(b);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
double x1 = 15.0, y1 = 15.0;
double x2 = 25.5, y2 = 37.25;

Distances.euclidean(x1 - x2, y1 - y2); // order does not matter
Distances.euclidean(y2 - y1, x1 - x2); // distance is the same regardless

Distances.manhatten(x1 - x2, y1 - y2);
```

Comment: You should not name your class 'Distances' if you are calculating Norms with it ;)